# Restricción de ingreso de datos en un campo de texto HTML5

Tags: html5

Hola tengo una duda  y es que tengo un campo de tipo texto y en vez de que ingrese datos de tipo texto y numérico solo se ingrese de tipo numerario son tener que cambiar el tipo de campo

```
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="documento_E" name = "documento_E" placeholder="Ingrese el Documento del Usuario"
         required pattern="[0-9]{5-20}" title="SOLO SE PERMITEN NUMEROS">
```

Comment: Puedes configurar un campo para que sólo acepte números `<input type="number">`

Comment: Gracias, pero yo trato de decir sin tener que un dato de este tipo que solo sea dato de tipo texto y que solo admita números

Comment: Ya tienes un pattern puesto en el que solo admites números, mas de 5 y menos de 20. No funciona?

Comment: no funciona ya lo he probado, pero ya me respondieron como yo lo quería Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos HTML por defecto ya trae el tipo numerico, el cual permite validar que solo acepte numeros para esto se lo declara asi:

```
<input type="number" />
```

bien si deseas que se ingrese dentro de un rango como de 0 a 10 puedes hacerlo asi:

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="10" />
```

Ahora bien para tener una mejor validación de datos puedes usar algo de JavaScript:

```js
//esta funcion permite aplicar filtros a los input
function setInputFilter(textbox, inputFilter) {
  ["input", "keydown", "keyup", "mousedown", "mouseup", "select", "contextmenu", "drop"].forEach(function(event) {
    textbox.addEventListener(event, function() {
      if (inputFilter(this.value)) {
        this.oldValue = this.value;
        this.oldSelectionStart = this.selectionStart;
        this.oldSelectionEnd = this.selectionEnd;
      } else if (this.hasOwnProperty("oldValue")) {
        this.value = this.oldValue;
        this.setSelectionRange(this.oldSelectionStart, this.oldSelectionEnd);
      }
    });
  });
}

//define el input solo integer
setInputFilter(document.getElementById("documento"), function(value) {
  //FILTRO O EXPRESION REGULAR PARA VALIDAR LOS DATOS DEL INPUT
  return /^\d*$/.test(value);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="documento" name="documento">
```

Para aceptar solo **números enteros** sean **negativos** o **positivos** usa la siguiente expresión regular:

```
/^-?\d*$/.test(value)
```

**Solo números entero:**

```
/^\d*$/.test(value)
```

Numeros Enteros con limite(500):

```
/^\d*$/.test(value) && (value === "" || parseInt(value) <= 500)
```

Existen muchas formas de validar un **input** espero te sirva y suerte..!!